# Error trying to create direct stream between Spark and Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to follow this guide to enable my Spark shell to stream data from a Kafka topic http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

In my Spark shell I go to run this code.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "testid",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("my_topic")
topics.map(_.toString).toSet

val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
 sc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
```

It seems to work up until the createDirectStream method. At that point I am getting this error.

```
scala> val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
     |  sc,
     |   PreferConsistent,
     |   Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
     | )
<console>:35: error: overloaded method value createDirectStream with alternatives:
  (jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy,consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String],perPartitionConfig: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.PerPartitionConfig)org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]] <and>
  (jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy,consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String])org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]] <and>
  (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy,consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String],perPartitionConfig: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.PerPartitionConfig)org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]] <and>
  (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,locationStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy,consumerStrategy: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[String,String]]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategy, org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy[String,String])
       val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
                                                 ^
```

[image]

Comment: your first argument to the `createDirectStream` method is a `org.apache.spark.SparkContext` object, it needs to be a `org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext` object. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext

Comment: Thank you for the help! I created a streaming context with `val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))`. This fixed the error I was getting.